# Mensagem ao usuário ao não selecionar tamanho e cor com select

Tags: jquery, css, jalert

Estou precisando alterar um script que tenho e estou tendo alguma dificuldade, preciso dar um `Alert` para o usuário se ele tentar ir para o carrinho sem selecionar a opção de `Tamanho` e `Cor`, o evento até funciona, mas sempre cai na primeira mensagem, a do tamanho.

O formulário é esse:

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#Finaliza').click(function () {
        if (!$("input[type='select'][name='Tamanho']").is(':selected')) {
            jAlert("TAMANHO\nPor favor, selecione o tamanho para o modelo.");
            //alert("COR\nPor favor, selecione a cor para o modelo.");
            return false;
        } else if (!$("input[type='select'][name='Cor']").is(':selected')) {
            jAlert("COR\nPor favor, selecione a cor para o modelo.");
            //alert("TAMANHO\nPor favor, selecione o tamanho para o modelo.");
            return false;
        } else {
            var $cod = $("#cod").val();
   var $categoria = $("#categoria").val();
   var $tam = $("input[name='Tamanho']:selected").val();
   var $cor = $("input[name='Cor']:selected").val();     
        }
    });
});
```

```html
<form action="#" class="row variable">
 <div class="col-sm-6">
  <div class="form-group selectpicker-wrapper">
   <label for="Tamanho">Size</label>
   <select name="Tamanho" class="selectpicker input-price" data-live-search="true" data-width="100%" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Select">
    <option>TAMANHO</option>
    <?php foreach ($ResTamanho as $ResTamanhoSel) { ?>
    <option value="<?php echo $ResTamanhoSel->IdTamanho ?>"><?php echo $ResTamanhoSel->Nome; ?></option>
    <?php } ?>
   </select>
  </div>
 </div>
 <div class="col-sm-6">
  <div class="form-group selectpicker-wrapper">
   <label for="Cor">Color</label>
   <select name="Cor" class="selectpicker input-price" data-live-search="true" data-width="100%" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Select">
    <option>COR</option>
    <?php foreach ($ResCor as $ResCorSel) { ?>
    <option value="<?php echo $ResCorSel->IdCor ?>"><?php echo $ResCorSel->NomeCor; ?></option>
    <?php } ?>
   </select>
  </div>
 </div>
</form>

<div class="buttons">
<button class="btn btn-theme btn-cart btn-icon-left" type="submit" id="Finaliza"><i class="fa fa-shopping-cart"></i>CARRINHO</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Altere os seletores dos `if`s para verificar se algum option foi selecionado que não seja o primeiro:

```
!$("select[name='Tamanho'] option").not(":first").is(":selected")
```

e

```
!$("select[name='Cor'] option").not(":first").is(":selected")
```

Não precisa usar `input[type='select']`, basta `select[name=NOME]`.

**Exemplo:**

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#Finaliza').click(function () {
        if (!$("select[name='Tamanho'] option").not(":first").is(":selected")) {
            alert("TAMANHO\nPor favor, selecione o tamanho para o modelo.");
            return false;
        } else if (!$("select[name='Cor'] option").not(":first").is(":selected")) {
            alert("COR\nPor favor, selecione a cor para o modelo.");
            return false;
        } else {
            alert("ok");
        }
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form action="#" class="row variable">
 <div class="col-sm-6">
  <div class="form-group selectpicker-wrapper">
   <label for="Tamanho">Size</label>
   <select name="Tamanho" class="selectpicker input-price" data-live-search="true" data-width="100%" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Select">
    <option>TAMANHO</option>
    <option value="1">32</option>
   </select>
  </div>
 </div>
 <div class="col-sm-6">
  <div class="form-group selectpicker-wrapper">
   <label for="Cor">Color</label>
   <select name="Cor" class="selectpicker input-price" data-live-search="true" data-width="100%" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Select">
    <option>COR</option>
    <option value="1">Verde</option>
   </select>
  </div>
 </div>
</form>
<div class="buttons">
<button class="btn btn-theme btn-cart btn-icon-left" type="submit" id="Finaliza"><i class="fa fa-shopping-cart"></i>CARRINHO</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Valeu pela ajuda e explicação @sam.